# Cannot connect to gcloud instance via SSH

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, gcloud, ssh-keys

I am getting error while trying to do ssh gcloud instance.
I have removed old ssh key and regenerated new ssh key and tried to connect but still the problem remains as it is.

Please share your suggestions.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the port 22 is open in the firewall for that specific instance. You can follow this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) to manage your firewall rules. You can try [connecting via serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) instead. The issue you are facing could arise due to many different reasons. It is worth trying different [troubleshooting steps for SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) connectivity.

If you created [new SSH key](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys) properly then check if you added the key to your instance or project-wide metadata. This [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide) is a good read.